# How to retrieve and list data from sdcard in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-os

```
link.onclick = function() {
    console.log("display  started");
    link.style.background = "red";
    link.style.color = "black";
    listContents('music');
}

function listContents(storagename) {
    //Clear up the list first
    //  results.html("");
    var files = navigator.getDeviceStorage(storagename);
    console.log("files object "+files);
    var cursor = files.enumerate();
    console.log("cursore object "+cursor);
    cursor.onsuccess = function () {
        //alert("Got something");
        var file = this.result;
        if (file != null) {
            var imageElement = $('<img height="100" width="75">');
            imageElement.attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
            $("<p>" + file.name + "," + file.lastModifiedDate + "," + file.type + "," + file.size  + "</p>").appendTo('#results');
            imageElement.appendTo("#results");
            this.done = false;
        } else {
            this.done = true;
        }

        if (!this.done) {
            this.continue();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, on click of link button I want all the audio files to be displayed in a list. A sample function for it is given, but it is in jquery. I want to implement the function `listContents()` using pure JavaScript.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Whatever you want to do, you shouldn't change the value of `this.done`. Apart from that, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to write this code in java script here it is given in jquery ..and i dont kwn how to convert is from Jquery to java script.

Comment: I don't see that any efforts have been made from your side to solve the problem by yourself. Please provide clearly indented code next time. Regarding your question, I recommend you to learn the basics of JavaScript DOM manipulation. What you're asking for is really basic and shouldn't be something to ask on SO!

Comment: I knw it is basic and i tried to write this code in java script i was stuck at some place where i was getting null result and i wanted to solve that problem so i have uploaded this question.But now i have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#elements) – the `Elements` section in particular might prove to be most helpful.

This reference alone *would not solve your problem* right away, but could generally point you in the right direction. Most of the "pure JavaScript" techniques (like the DOM method `element.querySelectorAll`) do not return an object as convenient as its jQuery counterpart does, so you will certainly need a bit of hacking, trial and error to get this to work — but ultimately I think that is the best way to learn this. :)

Learning a thing or two about functions like [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), `element.innerHTML` & [`element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)/[`element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) should get you started. ;)